# Laravel Passing ID from fetched data to AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm at lost on what is the way to do this. So basically i got a multiple comment form like this :

```
@foreach($lists as $list)
    //some views 

    <form class="commentForm">
        <input type="text" class="commentBox" name="comment" />
        <input type="submit" class="submitBtn" value="Comment" />
    </form>
@endforeach
```

And i want to implement AJAX so that every time user comment something, the page won't reload. My current route for submitting the comment is :

```
Route::post('list/{listID}/comment', 'ListController@comment');
```

And i don't know how to pass that ID from the view to AJAX and then back to controller. I tried to obvious one, use `'list/{{ $list->id }}/comment'` in the AJAX url, that didn't work. Also tried some other things but basically all for naught.

Thank you in advance !

EDIT : My AJAX code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on("submit", '.commentForm', function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var data = $(this).serialize();
    var me= this;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'posts/{{ $auction->id }}/comment',
        data: data,
        datatype: 'JSON',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
})
});
```

I just console.log-ing the outputs for now to see whether it works not.

Comment: Where is the id in the view?  Wouldn't each commentBox have its own id? Not seeing it in the DOM.

Comment: post your ajax code?

Comment: @larsAnders That's what i am currently confused about, where to put the ID. The comment below said that i can use input type hidden but from the video i watch, he said that you should avoid using those when working with Laravel...

Comment: @crystalwill edited above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel, they use blade templating. I dont know where you put your ajax code, but these bracket: {{ }}, {!! !!} only will be considered as templating when you use the extension .blade.php.

In laravel you can use .php under resource/views as the html template, but the one inside {{ }}, {!! !!}, and other blade syntax will be treated as normal text instead of being interpreted again. If you need, usually i will make the layout will be something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        @yield("sytles")
        @yield("additionalstyles")
        @yield("includestyles")
        ................//as many as you need
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>@yield("content")</div>//content here
        @yield("scripts")
        @yield("additionalscripts")
        @yield("includescripts")
        ................//as many as you need
    </body>
</html>
```

and then in the view, when i need to make ajax request, i will enclose it inside the @section("script") @stop or whichever the yield that haven't been used yet, so for example the view part of your code maybe will be like this after using this template:

```
@extends("layout")

@section("content")
@foreach($lists as $list)
    //some views 

    <form class="commentForm">
        <input type="text" class="commentBox" name="comment" />
        <input type="submit" class="submitBtn" value="Comment" />
    </form>
@endforeach
@stop

@section("additionalscript")
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("submit", '.commentForm', function(e){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var me= this;

        $.ajax({    
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'posts/{{ $auction->id }}/comment',
            data: data,
            datatype: 'JSON',
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    })
    });
</script>
@stop
```

In this way, your

```
url: 'posts/{{ $auction->id }}/comment',
```

will going to be rendered as something like

```
url: 'posts/hansishandsome/comment',
```

Hope this help

Comment: Ah yeah, because i put the js on the other files that's why the braces didn't work. Thanks !

Comment: Note that this will only work if you have one and only one form on the page. As soon as you have multiple forms, a hard-coded id in the javascript will not work.

Comment: The typical of CRUD in laravel will always most likely, doing one form per page, and then pass to server and refresh the page, even though using AJAX to send the request to server, i noticed that the usage foreach syntax there means that he render one post for the whole page. You can also still able to have multiple form inside one page in this style, but not for the .commentForm, as long as it's other form, still can be done.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using jQuery's `.data()` feature, so in the foreach loop you do this:

```
<form class="commentForm" data-id="{{$list->id}}">
    <input type="text" class="commentBox" name="comment" />
    <input type="submit" class="submitBtn" value="Comment" />
</form>
```

Then one listener to rule them all:

```
$(document).on("submit", '.commentForm', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     var comment_id = $(this).data('id');
     console.log('comment id = ',comment_id);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'posts/' + comment_id + '/comment',
        //etc...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following steps:

Add one hidden field with value as `Listid` in `form` like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="listId" value="{{$list->id}}" />
```

And then you can use it in ajax call like:

```
$listId = $("#listId").val();
```

Comment: Oh i thought about this actually, but from the video tutorial i watched, he said that you should avoid using input type hidden when working with Laravel. Is it ok for this instance or that guy is just wrong ?

Comment: Laravel itself provides hidden input field in its `blade` form syntax. e.g `{{ Form::hidden('list_id', $list->id) }}` . If it is not okey then laravel should not allow this too.

Answer (score 0):

These are the following ways you can do it

1. Create a hidden input

```html
<input type="hidden" id="listid" name="listid" value="{{ $list->id }}">
```

and read the value through JQuery

```js
var listid = $('#listid').val();
```

2. Create a JSON object and read it in your

```html
<script>
   var list = {
      id : {{ $list->id }} //you can also add other variables in the object
     }
</script>
```

And in your js file use the list object

**NOTE: the list object must initialized before you run your script**

```js
$.post('list/' + list.id + '/comment', data);
```